# Only change the state for the particular card component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, state

I have a state called "itemQty" where i want it to increase whenever the plus button is pressed and decrease whenever the minus button is pressed. However, now when i pressed the button, the state changes for every card in the page. I only one it to change in the card where the button is. I understand I have to use the key of the mapping. But I am not sure how to. Can someone help me?
This is where my both my qty will change to the same.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is my state where the default is set to 1. But when i press one the plus button on the first card, both quantity becomes 2.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemQty: 1,
    };
  }
```

This is my mapping for the products:

```
 <CardGroup>
                {this.props.restProducts.map((product, key) => {
                  if (
                    product.owner == hawker.owner &&
                    product.published == true
                  )
                    return (
                      <Col md={4}>
                        <Card style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
                          <Card.Img
                            style={{
                              width: 150,
                              height: 150,
                              alignSelf: "center",
                            }}
                            variant="top"
                            src={
                              "https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/" + product.imageHash
                            }
                          />
                          <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>
                              {" "}
                              {window.web3.utils.fromWei(
                                product.price.toString(),
                                "Ether"
                              )}{" "}
                              Eth
                            </Card.Text>
                          </Card.Body>
```

This is where i add the onclick event for the button icon:

```
  <FaMinusSquare
                              size="25"
                              onClick={(event) => {
                                console.log("Clicked Minus");
                                this.setState({
                                  itemQty: this.state.itemQty - 1,
                                });
                              }}
                              style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginRight: 5 }}
                            />
                            {this.state.itemQty}
                            <FaPlusSquare
                              size="25"
                              onClick={(key) => {
                                console.log("Clicked Plus");
                                this.setState({
                                  itemQty: this.state.itemQty + 1,
                                });
                              }}
                              style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginLeft: 5 }}
                            />
```

Comment: Please, add your code in text form not in images and consider putting it on codebox. I assume that you are changing a state, which provides data for multiple components/elements on the page, which creates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 options to do what you want:

1. Make every card item a component with its own state, which will include quantity and change it on single item level

```js
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       qnt: 0
    }
  }
  
  changeQntAdd() {
    this.setState({ qnt: this.state.qnt + 1 })
  }
  
  changeQntRemove() {
    this.setState({ qnt: this.state.qnt - 1 })
  }
  
  const product = props.product;
  return (
    <li>
      {product.name}
      <button onClick={changeQntAdd})>Add one</button>
      <button onClick={changeQntRemove})>Remove one</button>
    </li>
  );
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.products.map(product => <ListItem product={product} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Keep a global state with item quantity like: `this.state = { cards: [{id: 1, qnt: 1}, {id: 2, qnt: 12}] }`, and change the global state.

Option 2 is most likely the way you want to go with.

Comment: hi, do u know how i can go about doing the 1st option?

Comment: just make each card a separate react component, with separate state and the method to change this state. Like `this.props.restProducts.map((product, key) => { return (<CardItem key={key} product=product} />) })`

Comment: does this mean i can add qty={qty} in the <CartItem> also?

Comment: no, thats the point, if you want to change quantity of individual item, you must have individual state for each item

Comment: do u mind showing me an example? I am so sorry, i am very new to this and been stuck at it for so long